# How to write literal jQuery object in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to convert some code to coffeescript and I'm having problems with this:

```
var $el = $('<span/>', {
    class : 'myclass',
    click : function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        if (foo) { // radio & check
            baz($this)
        }else{
            bla($this)
        }
    }
});
```

I wrote in coffee like so:

```
$el = $('<span/>',
  class: 'myclass'
  click: ->
    $this = $(this)
    if foo
      baz $this
    else
      bla $this
)
```

Which works just fine, but I really dislike that last parenthesis, is there any way I could write this code without parens, just indentation?

Comment: I'm interested to know the motivation behind moving to coffee script. can you please share it with me?

Comment: I hope the fact that most javascript developers don't understand coffee script will keep that as experimental only... `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine if you drop both parentheses.

```
$el = $ "<span/>",
  class: "myclass"
  click: ->
    $this = $(this)
    if foo
      baz $this
    else
      bla $this
```

See also: http://js2coffee.org/